# find . -name "*.c" and find . -name "*.c" > o give different answers in deep directories

Tags: unix, command-line, find, dump

`find . -name "*.c"` returns the right thing, listing all the files with the whole full relative path from the point of execution (example):

```
./a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/file.c
```

`find . -name "*.c" > o` with the output going to a file substitutes the beginning of the path with the word "dump" (example):

```
./dump/g/h/file.c
```

Any idea why?

Comment: what is the actual path of the file?

Comment: Wow. This should not be happening. Just for shits and giggles, try "`find . -name "*.c" | tee list.txt`" and see what you get (both on the screen and in the file).

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you are not executing the second command in the same directory as the first. Is it part of a script?

Comment: Turns out find is outputing "./dump/g/h/file.c" for the first few files, so the output is the same on both cases, it's just that I wasn't seeing the first few with the "dump" on them. The question now is what is making it create this "dump" on the first few files. I removed half the files in the subdirs, and it's not doing the 'dump' anymore. Very strange.

Comment: Could you have a directory with 'funny' characters in the name, such as newline or carriage return (or vertical tab, or ...)?  These can lead to odd effects.

Comment: Do you have a directory named `dump`? What's the output of `ls -l dump/g/h/file.c`?

Comment: No funny directory or any directories named dump. The dump is really just shortening the full path. Thanks for the guesses though, I'm guessing here too..

Answer (score 1):

Find is returning all of the files from your current directory. You either have files that match the `*.c` pattern in the current directory which are included in the output, or there is a "find: *.c: No such file or directory" message on stderr that you're not telling us about.

Update:

Your question is now different. Answering your new question:

find does not change its behaviour depending on where its output is going. This means that you are either executing it under different conditions in your redirection test or the output in the file you are checking is not the real output from find.